# How is it possible for a quadratic equation to have one rational root and one irrational root?

Tags: roots, quadratics, radicals, irrational-numbers

The irrational root theorem says that irrational roots come in pairs. How are things like $x^{2}+\sqrt{2}x=0$ possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The irrational root theorem is true only if the coefficients are integers.

Comment: @Henry. To add to Luca's answer, you may substitute $x=\sqrt{2}t$ and your equation becomes $2t^2+2t=0$. Now if this equation has to have irrational roots, they must come in conjugate pairs. But here, the solutions are just integers, $0,-1$ Now back-substitution to get $x$ gives indeed....a rational solution and an irrational...

Comment: Does the theorem for imaginary numbers only work if the coefficients are integers?

Comment: More precisely, I suppose, only if the coefficients are rational numbers.